# Embedded C# web server with easy SSL support

Tags: c#, http, mono

I am looking for an embedded Web Server with out of the box SSL support, preferably configured from a command line or some easy config, without the need to change system wide config (like Registry). It should also work on mono.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried my old server http://webserver.codeplex.com? It supports SSL and at least used to run on MONO.

I'm also (slowly) building a new one, it got no SSL support yet (but's not that hard to implement by yourself): http://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.webserver

**Edit**

The HttpListener in Griffin.Framework have SSL support now

Comment: Watching your new component with great interest. Been using the old one for a long time now in my software - love it!

Comment: @jgauffin Keep up the good work on the new griffin.webserver :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across two such packages.

ceenhttpd  - https://github.com/kenkendk/ceenhttpd

and

uHttpSharp - https://github.com/Code-Sharp/uHttpSharp

The part i like about these is that both of them let you load a certificate file from disk. If you use the raw HtttpListener, that is a pain.

If you are open to use .NET Core, you can also self-host Kesterel. I plan to use this as soon as I convert my projects to .NET 5. [here is a small sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-5.0#get-started) code for that.