# SSL based webserver on Windows IoT

Tags: security, ssl, https, webserver, windows-iot-core-10

I am working on a project which involves gathering some sensor data and build a GUI on it, with controlling of sensors. It has following two basic requirements.

- Should be a web based solution (Although it will only be used on LAN or even same PC)
- It should be executable on both windows IoT core and standard windows PC (Windows 7 and above)

I have decided to use [Embedded webserver for Windows IoT](https://github.com/sensaura-public/iotweb), which seems to be a good embedded server based on PCL targeting .NET 4.5 and UWP. So I can execute it on both environments. That is great! But the problem is this web server doesn't support SSL, I have tried to search other servers and have come up with [Restup for UWP](https://github.com/tomkuijsten/restup), which is also a good REST based web server, but it also doesn't support SSL.

I needs an expert opinion, that if there is any possibility I can use SSL protocol in these web servers. Is it possible that it can be implemented using some libraries like `OpenSSL` etc? (Although I think that it would be too complex and much time taking to implement it correctly)

**Edit**

I would even like to know about ASP.NET core on `Windows 10 IoT Core`, if I can build an application for both windows. I found one [example](https://www.hackster.io/iddi/windows-10-iot-core-publish-asp-net-web-application-d9dcd4) but it is `DNX`based, and I don't want to follow this way, as `DNX` is deprecated.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could take a reference of [Embedded C# web server with easy SSL support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644018/embedded-c-sharp-web-server-with-easy-ssl-support) and [SSL Support (Windows Embedded CE 6.0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee500475(v=winembedded.60).aspx)

Comment: @JamesLiu I doubt if I can use this server of Windows IoT?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but .NET Core 2.0 looks promising with Kestrel. I successfully created a .Net Core 2.0 app on the PI 3 this morning. Pretty nifty and If you already have an Apache web server, you’re almost done. I’m actually going to embed (might not be the right term) my .Net Core 2.0 web application into a UWP app, rather than create multiple unique apps for the touchscreens around the house.

.Net Core 2.0 is still in preview though.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Can we embed .NET core app inside UWP background application? I doubt `https://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/32626766-support-for-asp-net-core-running-on-uwp-as-windows`. Additionally unless we have production build of .NET core for `ARM`, I think it is not a good idea to make apps for Windows IoT on .NET Core.

Comment: Yes, you can. However, like I said it’s still in preview. Maybe it’s not a good idea, but it does work. This is a neat tutorial. https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/03/21/step-by-step-running-aspnet-core-on-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is pretty old, but I have built the solution which you are asking bout. I’m currently running .Net 5.0 on a Raspberry pi. When you build the .net core web project, select the correct target framework and the target runtime to win-arm. Copy the output some directory on the pi and you will have to access the device using powershell to create a scheduled task to start the web project. Something like this:
`schtasks /create /tn "Startup Web" /tr c:\startup.bat /sc onstart /ru SYSTEM` 
That starts a bat file which runs a powershell command which has the following command:
`Set-Location C:\apps\vradWebServer\ .\VradTrackerWeb.exe` (the .\VradTrackerWeb.exe is on a second line in the file) - the name of the webapp.

That starts the server. If you have any web or apps posting to the webserver you will need an ssl cert. I used no-ip and let’s encrypt for this. For let’s encrypt to work, you will need an external facing web server and have the domain name point to it. Run let’s encrypt on the external server and then copy out the cert and place it in your web directory on the pi. I then have a uwp program that runs on the pi and when it starts, it gets it’s local address and then updates no-ip with the local address, so the local devices communicating will be correctly routed and have the ssl cert. Side note, my uwp app is the startup app on the device. The scheduled task is important because it allows you to run you app and the web server.  The following snip is how I get the ip address and then update no-ip.

```
    private string GetLocalIP()
    {
        string localIP = ""; 
        using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0))
        {
            socket.Connect("8.8.8.8", 65530);
            IPEndPoint endPoint = socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
            localIP = endPoint.Address.ToString();
        }
        return localIP;
    }//GetLocalIP


    private async void UpdateIP()
    {
        string localIP = ""; 
        string msg = "";

        var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("YourUserName", "YourPassword") });

        try
        {
            localIP = GetLocalIP();

            string noipuri = "http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update?hostname=YourDoman.hopto.org&myip=" + localIP;
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(noipuri))
            using (var content = response.Content)
            {
                msg= await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            if (msg.Contains("good") == true || msg.Contains("nochg")==true)
            {
                SentDynamicIP = true;
                LastIPAddress = localIP;
            }
            else
            {
                SentDynamicIP = false;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string x = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Dispose();
        }

    }//UpdateIP
```